# Segmentation fault (core dumped) eror in c++ (iterator overloading)

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I'm tring to implement the doubly linked list and also iterators and i only want to add a single node and test my print function which have iterators in it.but somehow ( i don't know really ) i'm facing the Segmentation fault (core dumped) eror and it's my first time facing this eror and i read about it and i understand the eror but i can't find where i do the mistake!

**doublylinkedlist.h**

```
#ifndef DoublyLinkedList_H
#define DoublyLinkedList_H

#include <iostream>
#ifndef DoublyLinkedList_H
#define DoublyLinkedList_H

#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class DoublyLinkedList;

// List Node class
template <class T>
class DoublyLinkedListNode
{
    friend class DoublyLinkedList<T>;
    friend class DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator_Base;
    friend class DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator;
    friend class DoublyLinkedList<T>::Reverse_Iterator;

private:
    T data;                         // data
    DoublyLinkedListNode<T> *llink; // left link
    DoublyLinkedListNode<T> *rlink; // right link
};

// List class
template <class T>
class DoublyLinkedList
{
public:
    typedef DoublyLinkedListNode<T> NodeType;

    // iterator
    class Iterator_Base
    {
    public:
        Iterator_Base(NodeType *startNode = 0) { current = startNode; }
        ~Iterator_Base() {}

        Iterator_Base(const Iterator_Base &source) { current = source.current; }

        // dereferencing operators
        T &operator*() const { return current->data; }
        T *operator->() const { return &current->data; }

        // get the node pointer directly
        NodeType *GetNodePointer() { return current; }

        // equality testing
        bool operator!=(const Iterator_Base it) const
        {
            return current != it.current;
        }
        bool operator==(const Iterator_Base it) const
        {
            return current == it.current;
        }

    protected:
        NodeType *current;
    };

    class Iterator : public Iterator_Base
    {
    public:
        Iterator(NodeType *startNode = 0) : Iterator_Base(startNode) {}
        Iterator &operator++();   // ToDo
        Iterator operator++(int); // ToDo
        Iterator &operator--();   // ToDo
        Iterator operator--(int); // ToDo
    };

    class Reverse_Iterator : public Iterator_Base
    {
    public:
        Reverse_Iterator(NodeType *startNode = 0) : Iterator_Base(startNode) {}
        Reverse_Iterator &operator++();   // ToDo
        Reverse_Iterator operator++(int); // ToDo
        Reverse_Iterator &operator--();   // ToDo
        Reverse_Iterator operator--(int); // ToDo
    };

    // Default constructor - ToDo
    DoublyLinkedList();

    // Copy constructor - ToDo
    DoublyLinkedList(const DoublyLinkedList &source);

    // Destructor - ToDo
    ~DoublyLinkedList();

    // Assignment operator - ToDo
    DoublyLinkedList &operator=(const DoublyLinkedList &source);

    // Get leftmost node iterator
    Iterator Begin() const
    {
        Iterator it(first);
        return ++it;
    };

    // Get end iterator
    Iterator End() const
    {
        Iterator it(first);
        return it;
    }

    // Get rightmost iterator
    Reverse_Iterator rBegin() const
    {
        Reverse_Iterator it(first);
        return ++it;
    };

    // Get end iterator
    Reverse_Iterator rEnd() const
    {
        Reverse_Iterator it(first);
        return it;
    }

    // Insert a new node to the list as the first node
    // Return the pointer of new node - ToDo
    Iterator InsertFirst(const T &data);

    // Insert a new node to the list as the last node
    // Return the pointer of new node - ToDo
    Iterator InsertLast(const T &data);

    // Insert a new node to the list after pos
    // Return the pointer of new node - ToDo
    Iterator InsertNext(Iterator pos, const T &data);

    // Insert a new node to the list before pos
    // Return the pointer of new node - ToDo
    Iterator InsertPrev(Iterator pos, const T &data);

    // Total number of nodes in the list - ToDo
    int Size() const;

    // Delete node at pos in the list - ToDo
    bool DeleteNode(Iterator pos);

    // Delete first node - ToDo
    bool DeleteFirst();

    // Delete last node - ToDo
    bool DeleteLast();

    // Print list
    void Print(bool reverse = false);

private:
    // first pointer of the list
    NodeType *first;
};

#ifndef DoublyLinkedList_TXX
#include "doublylinkedlist.txx"
#endif

#endif
```

**doublylinkedlist.txx**

```
#include "doublylinkedlist.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
template <class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator &
DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator::operator++()
{
    this->current = this->current->rlink;
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator
DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator::operator++(int)
{
    DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator temp = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return temp;
}

template <class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator &
DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator::operator--()
{
    this->current = this->current->llink;
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator
DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator::operator--(int)
{
    DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator temp = *this;
    --(*this);
    return temp;
}

/*
 * Reverse Iterator
 */

template <class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Reverse_Iterator &
DoublyLinkedList<T>::Reverse_Iterator::operator++()
{
    this->current = this->current->llink;
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Reverse_Iterator
DoublyLinkedList<T>::Reverse_Iterator::operator++(int)
{
    DoublyLinkedList<T>::Reverse_Iterator temp = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return temp;
}

template <class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Reverse_Iterator &
DoublyLinkedList<T>::Reverse_Iterator::operator--()
{
    this->current = this->current->rlink;
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Reverse_Iterator
DoublyLinkedList<T>::Reverse_Iterator::operator--(int)
{
    DoublyLinkedList<T>::Reverse_Iterator temp = *this;
    --(*this);
    return temp;
}

/*
 * Doubly linked list
 */
// Default constructor
template <class T>
DoublyLinkedList<T>::DoublyLinkedList()
{
    this->first = NULL;
}

// Copy constructor
template <class T>
DoublyLinkedList<T>::DoublyLinkedList(const DoublyLinkedList &source)
{
    // ToDo
}

// Destructor
template <class T>
DoublyLinkedList<T>::~DoublyLinkedList()
{
    // ToDo
}
/*
// Assignment operator
template <class T>
DoublyLinkedList<T> &
DoublyLinkedList<T>::operator=(const DoublyLinkedList<T> &source)
{
    // ToDo
}

// Total number of nodes in the list
template <class T>
int DoublyLinkedList<T>::Size() const
{
    // ToDo
}
*/
// Insert a new node to the list as the first node
// Return the pointer of new node
template <class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator
// typename Iterator
DoublyLinkedList<T>::InsertFirst(const T &data)
{
    if (first != NULL)
    {
        printf("worked");
    }
    else
    {
        DoublyLinkedListNode<T> *newNode = new DoublyLinkedListNode<T>();
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->rlink = NULL;
        newNode->llink = NULL;
        this->first = newNode;
    }
}
/*
// Insert a new node to the list as the last node
// Return the pointer of new node
template <class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator
DoublyLinkedList<T>::InsertLast(const T &data)
{
    // ToDo
}

/*
// Insert a new node to the list after pos
// Return the pointer of new node
template <class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator
DoublyLinkedList<T>::InsertNext(DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator pos, const T &data)
{
    // ToDo
}

// Insert a new node to the list before pos
// Return the pointer of new node
template <class T>
typename DoublyLinkedList<T>::Iterator
DoublyLinkedList<T>::InsertPrev(Iterator, const T &data)
{
    // ToDo
}

// Delete node at pos in the list
template <class T>
bool DoublyLinkedList<T>::DeleteNode(Iterator pos)
{
    // ToDo
}

// Delete first node
template <class T>
bool DoublyLinkedList<T>::DeleteFirst()
{
    // ToDo
}

// Delete last node
template <class T>
bool DoublyLinkedList<T>::DeleteLast()
{
    // ToDo
}
*/
template <class T>
void DoublyLinkedList<T>::Print(bool reverse)
{
    if (reverse)
    {
        for (Reverse_Iterator rit = rBegin(); rit != rEnd(); rit++)
        {
            std::cout << *rit << ", ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (Iterator it = Begin(); it != End(); it++)
        {
            std::cout << *it << ", ";
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

i'm only using this in my main.cpp to test InsertFirst() and Print()

```
DoublyLinkedList<int> list;
list.InsertFirst(10);
list.Print();
```

**PS**
the goal of this code is to test the iterators for my print fucntion so thats why i comment other fucntions.

Comment: Your compiler should be complaining loudly. For example because you declare `InsertFirst` to return something, but you never do. I suggest you enable even more warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` with GCC and Clang, `/W4` with MSVC), and treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: As for the crash, `return ++it;` in the `Begin` function seems wrong. As do `Iterator it(first);` in the `End` function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you , i feel like an idiot ! i forget to return the value xD thank you for your help